# Showing that this set is closed or open in $\mathbb{R^d}$

Tags: general-topology

Show that the set is closed or open in $\mathbb{R^d}$

(a) d=3 S={${(x,y,z) \in \mathbb{R^3} | -1/2 \leq cos(yz) }$}

Ways to prove this in my toolkit:

Proof by showing a function is continuous iff for every closed set $K \subseteq \mathbb{R^n} $, $f^{-1}(K)$ is also closed.

Proof by showing that a closed set must contain all of its limit points (I'm fuzzy as to how to do this)

So trivially I can't prove this by the continuity property, so I must instead rely on the limit point property.

So I was thinking that since R is dense, the limit points of cos(yz) are all points on the range of the function [-1,1] so S cannot be closed since it does not contain all limit points. I don't know how I'd prove this though? If someone could suggest a book or series to learn proof methods and how to make proving things in general more intuitive that would be really nice.

Answer (score 2):

The best way to prove that the set is closed is to note that the function $f(x,y,z)=\cos (yz)$ is continuous (becasue composition of continuous maps is continuous) and the given set is nothing but $f^{-1} [-\frac 1 2 ,\infty)$.

Answer (score 1):

Take a sequence $a_n=(x_n,y_n,z_n) \in \S$ such that $a_n \to (x,y,z)$ in $\Bbb{R}^3$ with the usual metric.

We have then that $$x_n \to x$$ $$y_n \to y$$ $$z_n \to z$$

Then $z_ny_n \to zy$

Use  continuity of $\cos{x}$  and then you will have the conclusion